# Operator in the commutant with certain property

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $T$ is a bounded operator with nontrivial kernel (in my case it is actually finite dimensional kernel and the operator is quasinilpotent) acting on an infinite dimensional Banach space, can one always find an operator $S$ with non-trivial range that commutes with $T$ and such that $Ker{(T)}\cap\overline{Range(S)}=\{0\}$?

Edit: Is this true for matrices? If $A$ is a $n\times n$ non-zero matrix with non-trivial null space, can we find a matrix $B$ that commutes with $A$ and whose column space has trivial intersection with the null space of $A$?

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, an infinite dimensional example, a weighted left shift, can be constructed. If you make your post an answer, I will accept it, it certainly helped me.

Comment: Ok, answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we can't always find such an operator.

**Matrices**   Consider the matrix $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$. Its commutant is the set of all matrices of the form
$$
B=\pmatrix{a&b\\0&a}\quad a,b \in \mathbb{C}.
$$
It is easily seen that the range of any such nonzero matrix contains the vector $\pmatrix{1\\0}$ and therefore has nontrivial intersection with $\ker A$.

**Infinite dimension**   In the same spirit, consider the backward shift $A(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ over $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. Its commutant is the set all Toeplitz operators of the form
$$
B=\pmatrix{a_1&a_2& \ldots \\ 0&a_1&a_2&\ldots\\ &0&a_1&a_2\ldots\\ & &\ldots&\ldots}
$$
Again, we see that every such operator, provided it is nonzero, has a range containing $\pmatrix{1\\0\\\vdots}$ which spans $\ker A$.

**Finally**   To obtain a counterexample $A$ which is also quasinilpotent, you can use an appropriately weighted backward shift.